# Shiny dplor: getting error: Warning: Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I'm getting a data frame where collects users input (driver type) and use dplyr to filter out rows that %in% the data frame. However, I'm getting error like this:

> Warning: Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.

Not sure which part is missing.

```
  cmap <- reactive({
    range_1 <- as.numeric(input$range[1])
    range_2 <- as.numeric(input$range[2])
    type <-data.frame(value = as.character(paste(input$type)))

    temp <- df%>%
      filter(driver_type %in% type & 
               year_period >= range_1 & year_period <= range_2) %>%
      group_by(VIC_LGA__3) %>%
      mutate(Number_of_Drivers = n())

    temp<- select (temp, c(VIC_LGA__3,geometry,Number_of_Drivers))

    temp<- temp[!duplicated(temp$VIC_LGA__3), ]

  })
```

Comment: The repository is here https://github.com/lkjcbl/R-project

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by unlist the "type" data frame. adding one line:

```
type <-unlist(data.frame(value = as.character(paste(input$type))))
```